# How produce FormData object from custom object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm trying to form a FormData object before having the data from the form as a regular object. But at the output I get an empty FormData object

```
const submitForm = ( variables = {} ): Promise<any> => {
  const { body } = variables;

  const formData = getFormData(body);

  return httpClient.post('/submitAPI', formData);
};

function getFormData(object) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(key, object[key]));
  return formData;
}
```

Comment: logging form data usually represents empty object, try using `formData.get("try any key");` and log its value to see if it contains a value..